# Continuous deployment of django react project

Tags: reactjs, django, amazon-ec2, deployment, continuous-deployment

I have a react app with django backend. Every time when I need to deploy the app I have to follow following steps -

1. `Git pull` new django code
2. Copy react build from local to aws
3. Collect static files using `python manage.py collectstatic`

I have to automate this process using bare minimum dependencies. What can be done in such case?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: i think `docker` will do the thing.

Comment: @HemalPatel : Thanks , I had gone through the same thought but it still involves a learning curve.

Comment: yes but its worth